# GLFW mouse callback fired after mouse leave GLFWwindow?

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

For some reason my `Window::callback` is being called even after the mouse has left the window. I am unable to find a solution or even something that could help. Is it possible that GLFW updated how the mouse cursor callback operates? I wonder if it is an order of invocation problem?

Window

```
Window::Window(std::string title, int32_t width, int32_t height) {
    // TODO: add support for monitor and share for GLFW
    m_window = std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, GLFWdeleter>(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr));
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window.get());
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_window.get(), this);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(m_window.get(), Window::callback);
}

void Window::mouse_callback(double xpos, double ypos) {
    std::cout << "x: " << xpos << " y: " << ypos << std::endl;
}

void Window::callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    auto win = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    win->mouse_callback(xpos, ypos);
}
```

Engine

```
void startup() const
{
    if (glfwInit() == 0)
    {
        LOG(kError, "GLFW init failed!");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void Engine::run() {
    if (m_main_window_registered)
    {
        glewExperimental = static_cast<GLboolean>(true);
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    while(glfwWindowShouldClose(m_main_window->window()) == 0) {
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       glfwSwapBuffers(m_main_window->window());
       glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    g_engine.startup();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    auto window = std::make_unique<Window>("Hello World!", 640, 480);
    //window->make_current();
    g_engine.registerWindow(std::move(window));
    g_engine.run();

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 I added the the required material to deduce what might possibly be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem (or better put) issue is. On Windows the callback performs as expected where once the mouse leaves the windows area the callback stops firing. For OSX the window never loses focus and therefore the cursor callback is always being called. To fix the issue you simply have to test the coordinates to ensure that the mouse is in fact inside the window.