# GLFW Doesn't Detect Mouse Movement Outside GLFW Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw

`glfwSetCursorPosCallback()` only runs when the mouse is inside the window, but not when outside of it.

Earlier on today, I had this function working without any problem, but for the last few hours I have been stumped trying to discover the issue.

```
static void cursorPositionCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
 std::cout << xpos << " : " << ypos << std::endl;
}

.......

 while (!glfw.WindowShouldClose())  
 {
     shader.ClearBuffers(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glfw.ResizeWindow(MVP); 
     glfwSetCursorPosCallback(glfw.GetWindowID(), cursorPositionCallback);
     Cube_IBO.DrawElementsInstanced(CubeIndices.size(), 2);
     glfw.SwapBuffers(); 
 }
```

GLFW documentation states

> "This function sets the cursor position callback of the specified
> window, which is called when the cursor is moved".

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 16.0.4
- GLFW Version 3.3

Comment: I don't seem to understand what your issue is? GLFW explicitly states, as you said, that it only detects movement inside the window passed as an argument to the callback ([docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#cursor_pos)). So, what is the question here?

Comment: You might also want to try and move the `glfwSetCursorPosCallback(...)` outside, before  the `while` loop.

Comment: According to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265543/glfw-mouse-callback-fired-after-mouse-leave-glfwwindow the mouse movement is detected outside of the window on Mac but not on Windows.

The fact that this function does not work for me (Windows) outside of the GLFW window, but does in this video: https://youtu.be/EE5cS8EMT78?t=38 (Mac) seems to confirm this but I'm still not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

GLFW will detect the mouse movement only when the cursor is placed inside a GLFW window, as you say, GLFW documentation states it.

> "This function sets the cursor position callback of the specified
> window, which is called when the cursor is moved".

..Of the specified window.. unless you were using Mac